# How do i prove this $\frac{\sin^2(20)}{\sin(140)\sin(80)} = \frac{\cos(80)}{\cos(20)}$

Tags: trigonometry

How do you prove

$$\frac{\sin^2(20)}{\sin(140)\sin(80)} = \frac{\cos(80)}{\cos(20)}$$

Any help or hints will be appreciated. I have been stuck for quite some time!

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: After repeatedly using the double angle sin formula, I got this expression:

$\frac{1}{8cos^2(20)cos(40)}$

Comment: Hint:  $\sin (140)=\sin (40)$.

Comment: yup, I started out with that but not sure how to continue..

Comment: What have you tried? Show some of your steps.

Comment: Hint: to show these fractions are equal, repeatedly use $\sin x\cos x=\frac12\sin2x$ then $\sin x=\sin(180^\circ-x)$ to simplify their ratio.

Comment: @LionHeart thanks for your feedback, i have edited and included what i have attempted

Comment: @J.G. Thanks! i managed to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin^2(20)}{\sin(140) \sin(80)} = \frac{\sin^2(20)}{\sin(40) \sin(80)}=\frac{2 \sin(10) \cos(10) \sin(20)}{2 \sin(20) \cos(20) \sin(80)}=\frac{\cos(80) \sin(80)} {\cos(20) \sin(80)}=\frac{\cos(80)}{\cos(20)}$$

$\sin140=\sin40$

$\cos10=\sin80$

$\sin10=\cos80$

$\sin20=2\sin10 \cos10$

Answer (score 1):

You need only three facts to prove this:
$$
\sin(180^\circ-x)=\sin x
$$
and
$$
\sin x \cos x = \frac12\sin 2x
$$
and
$$
\sin x, \cos x\neq 0
$$
when $x$ is not a multiple of $90^\circ$.

The last fact means you can multiply out all of the denominators like $\cos 20^\circ$ without worrying.

Answer (score 1):

Using compound angle and double angle formula yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin 140^{\circ} \sin 80^{\circ} \cos 80^{\circ} &=\frac{1}{2} \sin 140^{\circ} \sin 160^{\circ} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos 20^{\circ}-\cos 300^{\circ}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos 20^{\circ}-\cos 60^{\circ}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \sin 20^{\circ} \sin 40^{\circ} \\
&=\sin^2 20^{\circ} \cos 20^{\circ}
\end{aligned}
$$
Rearranging yields
$$
\frac{\sin ^{2} 20^{\circ}}{\sin 140^{\circ} \sin 80^{\circ}}=\frac{\cos 80^{\circ}}{\cos 20^{\circ}}
$$